Is there a way to get an unique id from my cloud run service instance at runtime?
I would like to get a unique identifier from my cloud execution service instance (two instances running = two different IDs), so that this can be a key to my functions. Can be anything, but have to be unique.
I searched for default environment variables, but I didn't found one for my case.
Is there a way to do this at runtime?

You can use Instance metadata to get the instance's ID.
This instance ID is logged too.

IIRC the HTTP request includes a header with the instance ID.

Is it possible to shorten it, like picking the first 10 chars of a Git hash?

My current best guess is that at least 10 chars are required, 12 is better, but I couldn't find official documentation about it. Also the length is unclear: I get 134 chars in Cloud Run, while only 19 in Compute VM (if they can be related)
